# First order PDE, with 3 independent variables

Tags: partial-differential-equations, partial-derivative, chain-rule

I tried to solve the following PDE:

$$au_x+bu_y+cu_z=0$$

where $a,b,c \in \mathbb{C} $.

The results I obtained are the follwing:

$$
\begin{cases}
\frac{1}{a}dx=\frac{1}{b}dy\\
\frac{1}{b}dy=\frac{1}{c}dz
\end{cases}
$$

Solving this system

$$
\begin{cases}
bdx=ady\\
cdy=bdz
\end{cases}
$$

Integrating, yields

$$
\begin{cases}
b(x+K_1)=a(y+K_2)\\
c(y+K_3)=b(z+K_4)
\end{cases}
$$

Therefore

$$
\begin{cases}
\zeta_1:= aK_2-bK_1 = bx-ay\\
\zeta_2:= bK_4-cK_3 = cy-bz\\
\end{cases}
$$

So

$$u(x,y,z)=\Phi(\zeta_1,\zeta_2)=\Phi(bx-ay,cy-bz)$$

At this point, I needed to verify the solution, and I started like this:

Let $p=f(x,y,z)=bx-ay \quad$  and  $\quad q=g(x,y,z)=cy-bz$

So, using the chain rule, I wrote:

$$u_x = f_x\Phi_p + g_x\Phi_q = b\Phi_p$$
$$u_y = f_y\Phi_p + g_y\Phi_q = -a\Phi_p + c\Phi_q$$
$$u_z = f_z\Phi_p + g_z\Phi_q = -b\Phi_q$$

By substitution of these values in the PDE, I am not able to conclude.
Surely, I am getting wrong in some passages. 
Can anyone tell me how to do the correct ones?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: It might be convenient to write it as $(a,b,c)\cdot\nabla u=0$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your characteristic equation is correct and your solution is also correct.

Substituting this into the PDE you will obtain:

$$aF_x+bF_y+cF_z=a\left[\dfrac{\partial F}{\partial (bx-ay)}\dfrac{\partial (bx-ay)}{\partial x} +\dfrac{\partial F}{\partial (cy-bz)}\dfrac{\partial (cy-bz)}{\partial x}\right]$$
$$+b\left[\dfrac{\partial F}{\partial (bx-ay)}\dfrac{\partial (bx-ay)}{\partial y}+\dfrac{\partial F}{\partial (cy-bz)}\dfrac{\partial (cy-bz)}{\partial y}\right]$$
$$+c\left[\dfrac{\partial F}{\partial (bx-ay)}\dfrac{\partial (bx-ay)}{\partial z}+\dfrac{\partial F}{\partial (cy-bz)}\dfrac{\partial (cy-bz)}{\partial z}\right]$$

$$=a\left[\dfrac{\partial F}{\partial (bx-ay)}b +\dfrac{\partial F}{\partial (cy-bz)}\cdot 0\right]$$
$$+b\left[\dfrac{\partial F}{\partial (bx-ay)}(-a)+\dfrac{\partial F}{\partial (cy-bz)}c\right]$$
$$+c\left[\dfrac{\partial F}{\partial (bx-ay)}\cdot 0+\dfrac{\partial F}{\partial (cy-bz)}(-b)\right]=0$$
Can you complete it from here?

Comment: Yes! :) $$ a\left(b\frac{\partial\Phi(bx-ay,cy-bz)}{\partial(bx-ay)}\right)+ $$
$$ +b\left(-a\frac{\partial\Phi(bx-ay,cy-bz)}{\partial(bx-ay)}+ c\frac{\partial\Phi(bx-ay,cy-bz)}{\partial(cy-bz)}\right)+$$
$$+c\left(-b\frac{\partial\Phi(bx-ay,cy-bz)}{\partial(cy-bz)}\right)=0$$ That's perfect!